# .vimrc no hace efecto a menos que haga un ":source ~/.vimrc"

Tags: linux, vim, linux-mint

### Contexto.

Estoy comenzando a utilizar Vim, (especificamente NeoVim) y quiero personalizarlo comenzando con el arhivo `.vimrc`

### Problema.

Ya lo he creado en `/home/[miusuario]` pero para que pueda hacer efecto dentro de Vim tengo que obligatoriamente hacer un `:source ~/.vimrc`.

He visto bastantes foros y tutoriales en dónde explican que con solo tener el archivo en tu carpeta de usuario basta para que vim lo identifique pero en mi caso no es así. He buscado problemas de otros usuarios pero parece que nadie ha tenido mi problema.

Sospecho que probablemente es alguna tontería, pero no la encuentro. Gracias de Antemano.

Utilizo Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon Edition y NeoVim

Comment: vim y neovim son diferentes. Escribe `:h nvim-from-vim` y tomalo desde ahi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontré esto en un comentario a una respuesta en stack overflow en inglés.
En la respuesta se propone crear un link simbólico al archivo `.vimrc` mientras que otro propone agregar el `source ~/.vimrc` en el archivo que carga **neovim**

---

Respuesta

> Si alguien tiene este error al usar **neovim** te informo que el archivo
> `.vimrc` se carga desde `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`
>
> ```bash
> mkdir -p ~/.config/nvim; ln -s ~/.vimrc ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
> ```
>
> [Resupesta a: Not reading ~/.vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46994483/12812277)

Comentario

> Nota, puedes simplemente añadir `source ~/.vimrc` en las configuraciónes de `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` sin depender de links simbólicos.

---

Te recomiendo revisa si tienes el archivo `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` y si ya lo tienes solo agrega la linea `source ~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Ya realicé eso, pero sigue sin funcionar. Creé el archivo `/home/jesus/.config/nvim/init.vim` y puse lo que me dices y hasta reinicié la Laptop pero sigue sin funcionar :c

Answer (score -1):

La respuesta correcta es la del usuario [Alejandro00 en este mismo foro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/499904/202072)

El por qué no me funcionaba al principio, y espero le sirva a otro que tenga la misma duda es porque estaba ejecutando mi archivo con el comando `sudo` (`sudo nvim test.ts`)

Tiene sentido dado que esa configuración de `.vimrc` es para mi usuario llamado "jesus" y al ejecutarlo con sudo estoy es con el usuario "root" por lo que debo de ejecutar `nvim test.ts` en vez de `sudo nvim test.ts`

Comment: Si la respuesta correcta es la de Alejandro, lo en lugar de colocar esto en otra respuesta deberías marcar su respuesta como la respuesta aceptada y votarlo positivamente. Asi irias de acuerdo al formato del sitio.

Comment: ya lo realicé, gracias por el consejo @Pablochaches